# Android TTS sound Leaked Service Connection and speak deprecated

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, speech

I am using android tts in my class to just say a message like so:
Problem: I get leaked service connection

```
public class WorkTimerNotification extends ActionBarActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

   TextToSpeech tts;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_work_timer_notification);

    //line1
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this,this);



    @Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    //line2
    tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

    //line3
    tts.speak("Text to say aloud", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    tts.shutdown();

}


 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    tts.shutdown();
}
```

Line 1 I get leaked serviceConnection with this logcat:

```
 WorkTimerNotification has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@41aee290 that was originally bound here
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked
```

I press on this and it still goes back to the hash for some reason. I do not know why...

```
 int speak(CharSequence, int, Bundle, String)
```

I have also  tried: But it does not work either.

```
  @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    //Close the Text to Speech Library
    if(tts!= null) {

        tts.stop();
        ttsRest.shutdown();

        Log.d(TAG, "TTS Destroyed");
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Line 3 is deprecated since API 21, use `public int speak (CharSequence text, int queueMode, Bundle params, String utteranceId)` [instead](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#speak). Also `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated since the last AppCompat update. For your issue about no sound, I hope a more advanced user can solve this for you.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using public int speak (CharSequence text, int queueMode, Bundle params, String utteranceId) but it just reverted back to the old one. I don't understand why it keeps going back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not call `speak` until after `onInit` is called, move your `speak` code to `onInit`

```
public class WorkTimerNotification extends ActionBarActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

TextToSpeech tts;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_work_timer_notification);

//line1



}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
//line2
tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

//line3
tts.speak("Text to say aloud", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

}



@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    tts.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: When you call shutdown in onInit you probably will not hear anything since speak is asynchronous.

Comment: I figured, so where should I put it? Just keep it in onDestroy? I know that it just destroys the sound.

Comment: Also I get an error that it cannot end activity where it calls tts.shutdown as the error.

Comment: I had that though at the top, where I call private.

Comment: Assume i meant that it was within the public class {}. I still get same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78039/discussion-between-hoan-nguyen-and-bryn).